# Plotting random function in chart object

Tags: c#, charts, plot

I am trying to plot random function in my chart object. For starters, I wanted to plot this function in c#:

```
x^2 + 1
```

This is my approach

```
 for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(Math.Pow(x, 2)+1);
        }
```

It is throwing this kind of exception:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException
You can only set 1 Y value for this data point.
```

So How can I iterate through those points. According to this example I want to plot that function with 99 points.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're only passing one argument to the function. You need to pass both an X and a Y coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x, Math.Pow(x, 2)+1);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly, but It is showing only 1st quadrant (positive numbers), also if I change it only to x^2. It should look like this http://quickmath.com/images/gif/graphs/plot/example2.gif

Comment: Ok, Solved ... I had to change my for loop from -100 to 100 :)

Comment: I have one more question. What if I have more parameters in my function? I would like to plot this function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution .It has 4 parameters. Thank you

Comment: To plot a function with 4 parameters, you need to specify values for the other 3. You can only vary one variable along the x-axis at a time, so the other variables will need to be constant, or show them as different series.

Comment: like mmathis said, its impossible to _sanely_ plot a function with 4 parameters in one plot. What you do is, fix 3 parameters and plot the function. Then choose different coefficients and plot them again. It is also possible, to create a 3d Plot, there you only need to fix two parameters.